# af:inputDate is returning GMT instead of user selected date in ADF

Tags: timezone, oracle-adf

I am using af:inputDate tag to capture the date in adf.

My web page looks like -

[image: My web page looks like]

The date gets stored at `startDate` (which is `java.util.Date`).
Now after

```
    DataObjectEncodingUtils.encodeDate(startDate)
```

it is returning `2014-02-01 18:30:00` which is exactly 5.30 hours behind the selected date.

Here is the entry details in my trinidad-config.xml -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
     <trinidad-config xmlns="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/config">
       <skin-family>mySkin</skin-family>
       <formatting-locale>en_GB</formatting-locale>
       <time-zone>Asia/Calcutta</time-zone> 
       <!--<time-zone>IST</time-zone>-->
    </trinidad-config>
```

Am i missing something ?

-Amit

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an  component together with the inputDate? 
You can set the date format and the timezone in which you want the date displayed.